# What are the advantages of a more powerful console over the base model?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

I'm currently considering buying a console. I found that there are always a few models of the same console present on the market, e.g. Xbox One, Xbox One S, Xbox One X/PS4, PS4 Pro, etc. However, it's not quite clear for me as a consumer to have a more powerful (and hence more expensive) model of a console.

My understanding is that Playstation and Xbox games are designed so that they should work perfectly on either model, and I couldn't find if there are any restrictions or limitations between these models (like a game developed exclusively for a particular model of a console).

Of course there is the feature of playing a game in 4K, but is it the only reason for buying the Xbox One X or Playstation 4 Pro models?

Comment: You might want to reword your question to something like "What are the advantages of a more powerful console over the base model?". Because as it stands right now the question is opinion based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that PS/Xbox games are designed so that they should work perfectly on either model

This assumption is wrong. They're not designed to work perfectly on *any* model; they're designed to work perfectly on *one* model and on the rest they merely *work*. The later models have more processing power; a game with graphics that were optimized for a later model will probably have a crappy frame rate on an earlier one.

It's also largely thanks to advertising: if customers think that the new model is the "hot new console", they're much more likely to buy it.

Comment: This used to be a PC problem.  I see the consoles have caught up.  I now have no reason whatsoever to get a console...